# Grouping items in Dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame in python which contains the following fields:

```
id      date            cost    
A       2017-01-17      19
A       2017-01-17      22
A       2017-03-29      19
A       2017-03-29      10
B       2017-03-16      25
```

is it possible to group data frame on two columns `id` and `date`, then based on the grouping get max and min `cost`.

```
id      date            max(cost)   min(cost)   
A       2017-01-17      22           19
A       2017-03-29      19           10
B       2017-03-16      25           25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `agg`:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'date']).cost\
      .agg([('cost(max)', 'max'), ('cost(min)', 'min')]).reset_index()

  id        date  cost(max)  cost(min)
0  A  2017-01-17         22         19
1  A  2017-03-29         19         10
2  B  2017-03-16         25         25
```

Comment: so quick LOL :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
d={'max(cost)':'max','min(cost)':'min'}
df.groupby(['id', 'date'],as_index=False).cost.agg(d)
Out[1017]: 
  id        date  max(cost)  min(cost)
0  A  2017-01-17         22         19
1  A  2017-03-29         19         10
2  B  2017-03-16         25         25
```

Or using `apply`

```
df.groupby(['id', 'date'],as_index=False).cost.apply(lambda x : pd.Series([min(x),max(x)],index=['min(cost)','max(cost)']))
Out[1021]: 
               min(cost)  max(cost)
id date                            
A  2017-01-17         19         22
   2017-03-29         10         19
B  2017-03-16         25         25
```